# Interval variables in MIP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint-programming, binary-variable

In Constraint Programming it is possible to use *interval variables* to represent intervals of time during which something happens [(see here)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_scheduling_interval.html), usable in scheduling problems, for example.

**Is there something similar in MIP?** I am aware of some modeling approaches in MIP using binary variables to represent the order of jobs on a machine (i.e. $y_{ij}$ equal to 1 if job $i$ is worked before job $j$), but I was wondering whether other modeling approaches referring to intervals exist in MIP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single entity in MIP modeling that is a direct analog of an interval variable. The general MIP approach is as follows:

1. discretize the time domain (which is inherent in CP models using interval variables);
2. in lieu of a single interval variable, create a binary variable for each possible starting time and add a constraint setting the sum of those variables equal to 1 (so that you start at exactly one time epoch) or less than equal to 1 (so that you start once or not at all -- the analog to an optional interval variable);
3. use a constraint to define the ending time (a continuous variable) in terms of the processing time/interval width plus the starting time (an expression using those binary variables);
4. handle non-overlap requirements using constraints (involving all those binary variables) that say one interval either starts after the other ends or ends before the other starts.

In modeling terms, it's a bigger PITA than expressing the same concepts in a CP model ... but it is doable.

Comment: Regarding point 3, is there a particular reason to define the ending time rather than the starting time? I have seen a couple of papers doing this, but I don't understand whether is conventional or there is a benefit out of it.

Comment: It's not either-or; I assumed you already had variables for start times and was suggesting adding variables for end times. They are not necessary, but they make the non-overlap constraints easier to read (and possibly less susceptible to input error).

Answer (score 6):

The [vehicle routing problem with time windows](http://www.bernabe.dorronsoro.es/vrp/data/articles/VRPTW.pdf) is the first problem that comes to my mind, well researched, highly applicable. There are usually continuous variables that represent the visit (or start of service) time of a vehicle at a customer; that time must fall into a time window, which is an interval.

Answer (score 6):

To complete @Marco Lübbecke said, There are many scheduling problems which use binary and continuous variables to represent the interval of time. For instance, machine scheduling problems use such a method to calculate the intervals. (start time or compilation time.)

If you are interested to develop a MIP formulation, I recommended some references like:

A) [Scheduling (Theory, Algorithms, and Systems)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781489990433)

B) [Scheduling in Supply Chains Using Mixed Integer Programming](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118029114)

It should be noted that MIPs are usually NP-hard (They are difficult to solve), specifically in the real world situation even by using some commercial solvers like CPLEX or GUROBI, for large-scale models.

However, some useful approaches such as constraint programming (CP) can be applied to solve large-scale problems in a reasonable and efficient way.